# What is the 'state' parameter about on Apache?

Tags: apache, apache2, state, vhosts

We have a Symfony framework application whereby users log in with Google that system has multiple features. One being a task timing app. A user opened an existing tab with the timer app but was lead to a https://www.example.com/?state=eyS1cm2iOm3... (state parameter = 536 alphanumeric characters).

This loaded the 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page' default page instead of redirecting to the original state of the timer app. The same URL on the local and developement environments redirected correctly to the timer app. But on the prooooduction environment it sticks to the 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page'. Why is this?

I have seen the Apache sites enabled on all 3 environments and only the correct vhosts exist.

Comment: check on your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf if :
`IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`
was uncommented

Add your vhost and apache conf to make it easy to resolve

Comment: Thanks for the comment @seddik-omar - though I did check that too. It is uncommented on all 3 environments as well. Under sites enabled, we only have the 2 vhosts pointing to the correct web app directories as expected. Any other idea?

Comment: Try to disable default vhost : `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`
`service apache2 reload`

Comment: `ERROR: Site 000--default does not exist!`

I get this ... Also I only have 2 site under enabled for the application